# Can you link ng-options values together?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Forgive the terminology, but can you link ng-options values together?

This is what I have:

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_cusPro" 
       name="cusPro" ng-model="rentalAgreement.customerProfile" 
       ng-options="cusPro as cusPro.Name for cusPro in cuspros track by cusPro.id">
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Is there away to do `ng-options="cusPro as cusPro.Name` **and** `cusPro.id` `for cusPro in cuspros track by cusPro.id`.

That way the options would be like this:

```
       Name1 ID1, Name2 ID2  etc...
```

Instead of just

```
       Name1, Name2, etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_cusPro" name="cusPro" ng-model="rentalAgreement.customerProfile" ng-options="cusPro as cusPro.Name+' ('+cusPro.id+')' for cusPro in cuspros track by cusPro.id">
 <option value=""></option>
```

Comment: That was easy - Lol didn't know you could do that.